# Axis Camera video streaming with C# 64bit

Tags: c#, wpf, directshow, rtsp, ms-media-foundation

I'm looking for a way to stream video from an AXIS M10 IP camera, and display the feed using windows forms (or better, wpf). However, it need to be running on ***64-bit*** platform.

This means that I can't use the AXIS Media Control ActiveX component.
Also, I found that these methods work but only in 32bit environment:

1.[Using MediaElement Class for WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.aspx)

2.[Using embedded media player](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562851%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

3.VlcLib ([for dotnet](http://vlcdotnet.codeplex.com/))

So far it looks like my only option is to directly implement RTSP protocol and decode the given RTP/AVP stream using Media Foundation (for .net) and display it somehow. (I was able to get the camera to stream to a UDP port using RTSP calls).

I'm fairly new to RTSP/streaming, so I'm concerned that I might be missing the big picture - Will I be able to use media foundation to render/display videos on winform/wpf, or do I have to look at that functionality elsewhere?(from my research it looked like it could decode H.264 streams, but I did not see any video-playing capabilities). I also came across DirectShow - should I use DirectShow over Media Foundation?

Or better yet, is there a library that is able to handle RTSP streaming that runs in 64bit?

Comment: Both DirectShow and MF have 64-bit H.264 decoders, stock and third party. And both of them don't do RTSP for you. Getting H.264 from RTP is certainly doable, however not straightforward. For JPEG over HTTP x64 video you can use my DirectShow source filter http://alax.info/blog/1223

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[VisioForge Video Capture SDK .Net](http://visioforge.com/video-capture-sdk-net2.html) for example (but commercial), WPF controls included.
Decoding using FFMPEG, with DirectShow engine. Really, I don't see any Media Foundation advantages here.

Also any other way using FFMPEG.

Or, you can write RTSP source filter (based on DirectShow Push Source sample) with H264 output pin for video and G726/G711/AAC for audio. Also you can made virtual video capture source filter and use it in MF or DirectShow. You can use [live555](http://www.live555.com/) library for RTSP implementation.

So, no simple ways here, if you are starting from zero.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need the Video, I would prefer to just display the MJPEG stream of the camera. This is really easy done without the complexity of DirectShow or MediaFoundation. I display 12 cameras at the same time in my application with this little library in WPF: [MJPEG Decoder](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/MJPEG-Decoder). You can also use it in WinForms. It decodes the MJPEG Stream and gives you the images to display.

Comment: A lot of IP cameras deliver worse performance, frame rate, quality with JPEG encoding, and H.264 is more than reasonable, and it's delivered via RTSP...

Comment: I have 32 instances of the activeX Axis Media Control running on a single screen. I use 320x240 MJPEGs. It's working fine. I tried H.264, which requires *much more* CPU for only a few less network bandwith. I switched back to MJPEG.

Answer (score 1):

The 64 bits Axis Media Control SDK is available now, but requires an account on Axis web site to be downloaded.

After Sign in, you need to join [Axis Developper program](https://open.spotify.com/track/023H4I7HJnxRqsc9cqeFKV) (free) and download the [AMC SDK](https://www.axis.com/developer-community/media-control-sdk).

You will install a executable file (.exe), this install all the libs and samples in your Drive

> C:\Program Files\Axis Communication\SDK

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to use VLC in 64bits without ActiveX DLL :

The [VLCSharp Library](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp) is composed of multiple NuGets to use VLC Player on severals platforms (WPF, Winforms, Xamarion, TvOS).

It is working fine on Onvif Cameras